# For Loop in GRASS GIS console

Tags: bash, grass

I am trying to do a for loop in the Grass GIS 8.3 console and keep getting and error. How to execute a for loop in Grass GIS console?
Attached is an example of the error.[image: Error in GRASS GIS console]

I wanted to execute a for loop in the console and think that this is not the right way.

Comment: Don't unnecessarily post images, if you can do it as text as well. You get a syntax error in a script, so post the relevant part or the script. Also, your error message indicates that the error is produced from a Windows cmd or powershell script, so why are you tagging this _bash_?

Comment: That's a Windows error message. It seems like you're trying to use `bash` syntax in a batch script.

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR %%i IN (00 03 06 09 12 15 18 21) DO (
  gdal_translate -of GTiff NETCDF:"GLDAS_NOAH025_3H_A20220124.%%i00.nc4":Qair Qair_f_inst_GLDAS_NOAH025_3H_A20220124.%%i00_Qair.tif
)
```

I think this would be the correct way to transfer the bash format into batch. As I am an linux user this is my POV. I hope you got my point.